# When i pass base64 code to php through ajax it doesn't send full code. How do i solve it

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

When i pass base64 code to php through ajax it doesn't send full code. It receives only half codes from top remaining codes are missing. How to send full code using ajax jquery. Can you please help me to solve this problem. Here my code,

Here my php code,

```
if(isset($_POST['img_url'])){

    $img = $_POST['img_url'];
    echo $img;
}
```

Here my js code,

```
var img_url = "my base64 code for image";

      $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "http://www.aaaaa.com/jobsadmin/ajax_page.php",
        data: "img_url="+img_url,
        success:function(html){
          alert(html);
        }
      })
```

Comment: How big is the image? You might be hitting your PHP post_max_size limit

Comment: refer below link 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34779799/upload-base64-image-with-ajax

Comment: Image has been moved when i give base64 code directly. But when i pass base64 code from html page through jquery and ajax. I got some lines only remaining lines are missing

Comment: create json (json_encode) at the time of pssing base64 then read into php

Comment: Can u elobrate your thoughts i didn't understand your words

Comment: r u sure some base64 is missing ? can u post the output for this

`echo "<img src='".$img." /'>";`