# Send base64 image via ajax

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, api, base64

I need to send an image base64 encoded to an API. 
My json out put got only 10000 characters from the base64 code.

```
    var data = new Object(); 
    data.image= $('#image').val();
    data.date = new Date($.now()); 
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url:  app.url
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        contentType: "application/json",
        crossDomain: true,
        xhrFields: {
            withCredentials: true
        },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data, status, jqXHR) {
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, status) { 
        }
    });
```

In my console.log i've got the full string, but not in the request.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was just the chrome console/network display that is limited to 10000 char

Answer (score 0):

You would need to increase your server php.ini `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` or you can try this solution 
[Upload base64 image with Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34779799/upload-base64-image-with-ajax)

Comment: It was just the chrome console/network display that is limited to 10000 char