# Sending value in ajax call and reading it in page load

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I'm making an ajax call in the function as below

```
 function UploadPic() {
        debugger;
        // generate the image data
        var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
        var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");


        // Sending the image data to Server
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "baseimg.aspx",
            data: { imgBase64: dataURL },
            success: function () {
                alert("Done, Picture Uploaded.");
                window.opener.location.reload(true); // reloading Parent page

                window.close();
                window.opener.setVal(1);

                return false;
            }
        });
    }
```

And in the page load I'm trying to get the value as

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Request.InputStream); 
    string Data = Server.UrlDecode(reader.ReadToEnd());
    reader.Close();
}
```

In the dataURL I'm getting the value but in the page load 'string Data' is coming as empty.

I have referred to [Capturing Image From Web Cam in ASP.Net](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4d9083/capturing-image-from-web-cam-in-Asp-Net/) to make this functionality.

The ajax is hitting successfully to the code then coming back and executing the success portion in the ajax call.

I'm finding no way out of it.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a POST operation, try checking the form variable like the following for the data string:

```
Request.Form["imgBase64"]
```

Comment: Thank you so much but this is not working.There is no <form> tag in the page where I'm calling Ajax.The debugging just exits on this line no exception,no stopping of debugging .it is like a silent get out from debugging.

Comment: A form tag would not be necessary since you are invoking the post operation in AJAX...  Throw a breakpoint in the code-behind and watch the execution path it is following. Check to see if anything is posting back...

Comment: It is not returning anything back.I tried with the form tag but my Image capturing functionality is not working at all which is all written in Js.

Comment: Maybe this approach will work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34779799/upload-base64-image-with-ajax

Comment: What will be the best way  to get the value in code behind if the ajax is looks likes this <pre>    var formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('picture', blob);
            $.ajax({
                url: "baseimg.aspx",
                type: "POST",
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                data: formData
            })
        .done(function (e) {
            alert('done!');
        });</pre>

Comment: Tried converting and sending as blob. Still no go.