# Is it possible to move the image by $_POST not $_FILES?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Here is my piece of code.

process.php

```
$image = $_POST['image'];
```

index.php

```
<script>
function save(){
  var image = document.getElementById('image').files[0].name;

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'process.php',
    data: {
      image: image
    },
  });
}
</script>

<input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="image" name="image">
```

This basically returns only the file name to database mysql, but I don't know how to move the file from folder A to folder B. Which is the folder A is where the origin of the image lives, the folder B is when I want to call the image, I go with the path of folder B.

> Is it possible to move the image by $_POST not $_FILES? Because so far
>   I only find the $_FILES.

Comment: <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="image" name="image"> is inside the <form> .. ((forget to add <form>))

Comment: From my knowledge it is not possible, You can get file informations through $_FILES only

Comment: you cant do with post, you need `$_FILES`

Comment: why  you want to do with ```$_POST```?

Comment: What issue are you are trying to solve by using $_POST instead of $_FILES?

Comment: Any suggestion? Maybe some changes with the javascript?

Comment: @AndrewR So I have a problem with image upload with the script I have typed there. It should be using the FormData(). However, when data is submitted, the page redirect to another page. What I want is when the data/image is submitted, the page remains the same.

Comment: Honestly, your question is too vague to suggest a solution. Can you be more clear about exactly what you're trying to accomplish? What is your actual goal?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery AJAX file upload PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23980733/jquery-ajax-file-upload-php)

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34779799/upload-base64-image-with-ajax is a starting point for you

Comment: @WesleySmith <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block mb-4" name="but" id="but" value="Save" onclick="save()">

Comment: any `input type="button"` located inside a form element is automatically treated as a "submit" button and will submit the html form before the javascript you attach runs. Changing that to `<button class="btn btn-primary btn-block mb-4" id="but"  onclick="save()">Save </buton>` will stop that

Comment: That said, see the link I posted above, that will show you how to do the whole thing.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to send image as data url:

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" onchange="loadFile(event)">
<script>
var img = "";
  var loadFile = function(event) {
    var output = document.getElementById('output');
    img = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
  };
function save(){
  var image = img;
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'process.php',
    data: {
      image: image
    },
  });
}
</script>
```

Php:

```
$image = $_POST['image'];//now you can save the data url in database also
```

Comment: Please note that image size must be less than 1 mb otherwise some browsers would be crash!