# How to save base64 image using node js?

Tags: node.js, express

I am saving the base64 image using nodejs, it save my image at exact path, but show me the error.

Please help me to find the error.

[image]

Here is my code

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

const fs = require('fs');
const mime = require('mime');


const path = './uploads';

router.post('/register', (req, res, next) => {
  const base64Image = req.body.image;

  const matches = base64Image.match(/^data:([A-Za-z-+\/]+);base64,(.+)$/);
  response = {};
  if (matches.length !== 3) {
    return new Error('Invalid input String');
  }

  response.type = matches[1];
  response.data = new Buffer(matches[2]);
  let decodedImg = response;
  let imageBuffer = decodedImg.data;
  let type = decodedImg.type;
  let extension = mime.extension(type);
  let fileName = 'image.' + extension;

  try {
    fs.writeFileSync(path + '/' + fileName, imageBuffer, 'utf8');
    return res.send({ status: 'success' });
  } catch (e) {
    next(e);
  }

  return;

});

module.exports = router;
```

Any solution appreciated!

Comment: Shouldn't you decode base64 data before writing the file?

Comment: Can you please explain what you are trying to say @GrafiCode

Comment: Your image data is base64 encoded, right? When you write it on file, you should first decode it with `atob()`

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thanks

Comment: Why are you sending base64-encoded data to begin with?

Answer (score 7):

The mistake you made is when you are creating a buffer you are not specifying an encoding. You should create buffer like this:

> `new Buffer()` is deprecated use `Buffer.from()` instead.

`let buff =  Buffer.from(m[2],'base64');`  // encoding type base64

Basic code snippet

```
const fs =  require('fs')
let a =  'base64ImageString'
let m =  a.match(/^data:([A-Za-z-+\/]+);base64,(.+)$/);
  
let b =  Buffer.from(m[2],'base64');
fs.writeFile('image.png',b,function(err){
  if(!err){
    console.log("file is created")
  }
});
```

Also, when you writing a buffer to file you don't have to pass encoding type, but if writing string you have to.

Check this out for a demo
https://repl.it/repls/GrimOfficialLocations

> But it is not advised to send an image as base64 string. It is
> inefficient for large images. base64 roughly takes 33% more bits than
> its binary equivalent. I recommend you to check this out:
> [Upload base64 image with Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34779799/upload-base64-image-with-ajax)